# Upload file and parameters with ajax request, pure javascript or prototypejs

Tags: ajax, file-upload, prototypejs

I want to upload a file using an ajax request

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", "/photos");

xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined-binary');
xhr.sendAsBinary(bin);
```

Works fine, but I want to post a parameter with this request ie: token=abc123

How can give a parameter to this request?

this is pure javascript, if you have the answer using prototypejs it's even better

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still append query string parameters in a `POST` Request:

```
xhr.open("POST", "/photos/?token=abc123");
```